# fpost_t error due to incompatible types when assigning to type ‘fpos_t’

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
static void ITSReadNextLine(char *line, FILE *f, int fsize, int *eof) {

    fpos_t doneBytes = 0;

    if (fgets(line, LINE_BUFF_SIZE, f)) {
        if (fsize)
            fgetpos(f, &doneBytes);
        *eof = 0;
    } else {
        if (fsize)
            doneBytes = fsize;
        *eof = 1;
    }
    if (fsize)
        progress("ITS-Trace-File %i%% done", (int)((100 * doneBytes) / fsize));
}
```

I get these errors, which I don't understand:

```
decITS.c:145:1: error: invalid initializer
     fpos_t doneBytes =0;

decITS.c:152:26: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘fpos_t’ from type ‘int’
     if (fsize) doneBytes = fsize;
```

Answer (score 2):

> `fpos_t` "which is a complete object type other than an array type capable of recording all the information needed to specify uniquely every position within a file."

It is not certainly some numeric type (it could be a structure).

To initialize, change `fpos_t doneBytes = 0;` to `fpos_t doneBytes ={0};`.

To read its *value* as some integer is not something defined.

Code is trying to use `fpos_t` in a way it is not designed.

Answer (score 0):

The code to compute a progress meter is inconsistent: you use type `int` for the file size `fsize` and use `fgetpos()` to retrieve the current position as an `fpos_t`, which is not necessarily an integer type: `fpos_t` is probably defined as a structure on your system to account for line ending translation, the actual file position cannot be extracted portably from this type.

For a quick fix, you would use `ftell()` and hope the return value, which is a `long`, is more or less the offset from the beginning of the file, which is true on most unix systems but is not guaranteed by the C Standard for streams open in text mode, especially on systems where text mode translates the file contents:

```
static void ITSReadNextLine(char *line, FILE *f, long fsize, int *eof) {

    long doneBytes = 0;

    if (fgets(line, LINE_BUFF_SIZE, f)) {
        if (fsize)
            doneBytes = ftell(f);
        *eof = 0;
    } else {
        doneBytes = fsize;
        *eof = 1;
    }
    if (fsize) {
        progress("ITS-Trace-File %ld%% done", (int)((100LL * doneBytes) / fsize));
    }
}
```

Also note that your function should return the `eof` indicator instead of taking a pointer to a variable, and the length of the `line` destination array should be passed as an argument instead of assuming a length of `LINE_BUFF_SIZE`.

The approach should work for files up to 2GB, which is a reasonable limit for text files. Handling larger files n legacy systems with 32-bit `long` types requires extended APIs such as `ftell64()` which may or may not be available on your system, and opening the streams in binary mode is required to ensure that `ftell()` returns the offset from the beginning of the file.